# Vue JS changing data in one array changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i can't understand what the ... want this vue!
please help if you can!
this is my code

```
var groupadding = new Vue({
el: '#groupAdd',
data:{
     currentFullData: [],
     localData: []
   },
   methods: {
     getDepartment() {
       var sendData = id; // this is example
       this.$http.post('some api ', sendData, {emulateJSON: true})
       .then( resp => {
         this.currentFullData = resp.data;    
       }
     },
     getLocalDepartment() {
     this.localData = this.currentFullData;
     }
   }
})
```

in currentFullData for example i have 4 boolean field, 'create' , 'read', 'update', 'delete'

this 4 fields gets localData too, but when i change in localData some of them, they changes in currentFullData too!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

soooooo anyone can explain me wtf is this?!?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are actually modifying the same object (as you wrote `this.localData = this.currentFullData;`)

If you want to initialize this.localData using currentFullData, you need to copy it :

`this.localData = Object.assign({}, this.currentFullData);`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Oh nvm, I didn't see it was an array and not an object, see anchal20 answer for cloning and array.

Comment: sorry for my answer, you was right 
this.currentFullData = cloneArray(this.currentFullData, data);

function cloneArray($name, $array) {
 return $name = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($array));
}

this WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

thank YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. The issue is not with vue and the data values 'currentFullData' and 'localData'. As your data variables are Arrays, therefore when you assign the value like this `this.localData = this.currentFullData` then `this.localData` is a pointer to `this.currentFullData`. So, when you change localData then currentFullData also changes.
Thus, to avoid this, pass a reference of `this.currentFullData` to `this.localData` like this `this.localData = this.currentFullData.slice()`

For more understanding you can refer [this question about arrays on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.currentFullData.slice is not a function

Comment: You can check my codepen https://codepen.io/anchal20/pen/QMzQQG and also the link I shared above. I hope you are typing it correctly, it should be this.currentFullData.slice() and the resp.data should be of  array type.